# the code can not find the symbol but the symbol did exist in the market,why?

Tags: python, stock

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
all_data={}
fund = 14400
for ticker in ['CONG','CLIRW','MDLQ','ECC', 'ANDAW']
    try:
        all_data = web.get_data_yahoo(ticker,'01/01/2017',interval='w')
        sp = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
        if (sp['Close'][-1]>sp['Open'][-1]) and (sp['Close'][-2]>sp['Open'][-2]) and (sp['Close'][-3]>sp['Open'][-3]) and (sp['Close'][-1]>sp['Close'][-2]) and (sp['Close'][-2]>sp['Close'][-3]) :
            print(ticker,'    ','%.2f'%sp['Close'][-1],'    ',sp['Volume'][-1]//10000,'    ',fund//sp['Close'][-1])
    except:
        print ("Cant find ", ticker)
```

---

this code can print some symbol information I care,but some symbol can not be found but the symbol did exist in the market.How to fix it?

Comment: use `except Exception as ex: print(ex)` and you see urls - check this urls in browser and you see that this pages don't exist. Ask Yahoo why they don't exist :)

Comment: I will try and thank you for you hints. The ticker will can not be found do exits in Yahoo.

Comment: The ticker  can not be find by url. Which is better? yahoo finance or google finance? or other source?  except Exception as ex really helps me ,thank you .

Comment: I can't help with source I don't use any market source.